# Pausing HTML5 video transaction on the server

Tags: html, video

Is it possible that when I click on the pause control of a HTML5 video the video transaction pauses on the server?

Answer (score 0):

According the specifications (See http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-video-element): "*When a video element is paused and the current playback position is the first frame of video, the element represents the poster frame, unless a frame of video has already been shown, in which case the element represents the frame of video corresponding to the current playback position.
When a video element is paused at any other position, and the media resource has a video channel, the element represents the frame of video corresponding to the current playback position, or, if that is not yet available (e.g. because the video is seeking or buffering), the last frame of the video to have been rendered.*"

And the important part: "*User agents should provide controls to enable or disable the display of closed captions, audio description tracks, and other additional data associated with the video stream, though such features should, again, not interfere with the page's normal rendering.
User agents may allow users to view the video content in manners more suitable to the user (e.g. full-screen or in an independent resizable window). As for the other user interface features, controls to enable this should not interfere with the page's normal rendering unless the user agent is exposing a user interface. In such an independent context, however, user agents may make full user interfaces visible, with, e.g., play, pause, seeking, and volume controls, even if the controls attribute is absent.
**User agents may allow video playback to affect system features that could interfere with the user's experience**; for example, user agents could disable screensavers while video playback is in progress.*"

By my opinion the answer to your question is: it depends from User-agents (i.e. browsers) implementations, maybe in future we will see this feature available in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc. but for now pausing transaction when pausing video is not implemented.